# PostgreSQL : Backup script creating only once backup instead of hourly

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, cron, database-backups

I am working on a Debian system, where I have a PostgreSQL server running. I modified a backup script and installed a cron job to take hourly backups of our database, and store it in a folder. Along with that, there is a script executed, which deletes backups which are older than 3 days. I had installed that same script on 3 servers, and I saw that there was only one backup present. Instead of 15, as 15 hours have passed. What am I doing wrong, or is the deletion script wrong?

post_back.sh :

```
#! /bin/bash
DUMPALL='/usr/bin/pg_dumpall'
PGDUMP='/usr/bin/pg_dump'
PSQL='/usr/bin/psql'

# directory to save backups in, must be rwx by postgres user
BASE_DIR='/media/attachment/backups/postgres'
YMD=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%T")
DIR="$BASE_DIR/$YMD"
mkdir -p "$DIR"
cd "$DIR"

# get list of databases in system , exclude the tempate dbs
DBS=($($PSQL --list --tuples-only |
          awk '!/template[01]/ && $1 != "|" {print $1}'))

# first dump entire postgres database, including pg_shadow etc.
$DUMPALL --column-inserts | gzip -9 > "$DIR/db.out.gz"

# next dump globals (roles and tablespaces) only
$DUMPALL --globals-only | gzip -9 > "$DIR/globals.gz"

# now loop through each individual database and backup the
# schema and data separately
for database in "${DBS[@]}" ; do
    ALL="$DIR/$database.all.backup" 
 #dump all
    $PGDUMP -Fc "$database" > "$ALL"
done

# delete backup files older than 3 days
echo deleting old backup files:
find "$BASE_DIR/" -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime +3 -print0 |
    xargs -0r rm -rfv
```

cron job :

```
0 * * * * ./home/postgres/post_back.sh
```

ls command for backup dir :

```
/media/attachment/backups/postgres # ls
2016-09-13-14:00:01
```

Thank you.

Comment: One thing that irritates me is the dot at the beginning of the path in your cronjob. Is that a mistake? Perhaps the cron job fails before it can write any data. `cron` normally sends an e-mail with any output the script produces. Look for e-mails from cron and maybe ad some debugging output to your script so you can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe : How do you want me to call the script, when I call sh script name, it throws me some bracket errors, which makes no sense. So I had to add ./path/to/script. About emails. I have multiple scripts running, so I just now cleared all emails, I have to wait 1 hour for the mail to be generated. Can you tell me what I can add to script? Thank you.

Comment: Apart from the pathname(s), I would add some locking mechanism to avoid cron overrun.

Comment: If the path starts with `.` it is a *relative path* (relative to your current directory). In a `cron` job you want an *absolute path* (that starts with a `/`). About adding diagnostic output: Maybe things like `echo "global dump completed"` or `echo "dumping database $database"`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe : Okay, I will change it to 0 * * * * /home/postgres/post_back.sh . Add echoes and get back to you in 1 hour. Thank you.

Comment: @wildplasser : Added `lockfile -r 0 /tmp/the.lock || exit 1` at start of script and `rm -f /tmp/the.lock` at end of the script. Is that sufficient? Thank you.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe : Simply removing the dot before calling the command helped. Just checked, and all backups hourly are there. Just one last question. Can you check the deletion code at the end, does it look fine. Thank you. Also, please post an answer for me to accept. Thank you.

Comment: The deletion code looks ok, but I did not test it. Check in a week if it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the leading `.` in the path in the `crontab` entry.

You are advised to use absolute paths in `crontab`.